# Why does Minted color the first method of a c++ class differently?

Tags: minted

I am using minted to list c++ source code in LaTeX. When I compile the following sample I get a strange result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!tb]
\begin{minted}[linenos=true]{cpp}
class Gpio{
  public:
    static void setMode(uint32 pin, PIN_MODE mode);
    static void setValue(uint32 pin, PIN_VALUE mode);
    static void setPullUpDownMode(PUD_MODE mode);
  private:
};
\end{minted}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result I get looks like this:
[image: Minted C++ Example Result]

Does somebody have an idea why the first method is not colored blue?

It's always the first one, I have tried various numbers of public methods. Also if there is only one, it's still black and not blue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It doesn't seem to depend on `minted`, but rather on the Pygments library.

Comment: @egreg Which makes it questionable whether it's on-topic here. I would say it is fine, but SuperUser or StackOverflow would likely give the answer faster, if it was re-written in terms of Pygments.

Comment: @tohecz I'd wait for some other expert in minted/pygments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about Pygments rather than LaTeX/`minted`.